# Read-only file system in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

My computer has 4 partition. Beside of Ubuntu partitions, I have a partition to save working projects on same disk.

I use `gnome-disks` to auto-mount this partition when startup. However, when I create folder for create file,... I got messages like: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘e’: Read-only file system`.

I'm new to Linux, so if you want to know more abou my system, leave command line and I'll show you.

Thanks for any helps and so sorry about my poor English

Comment: What filesystem type is there? Is there Windows beside Ubuntu (dual boot)?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the output of the following command: `mount`

Comment: It is definitely mounted as read only. Mount output should help us identifying why is your partition read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments, I fixed it.

I install Window beside Ubuntu, Fast Startup of Window make disk not unmount. However, when I switch to Ubuntu, driver NTFS see that disk's mounting, so it mount read-only.

So I run `ntfsfix` (additionally, turn of fast startup on Window) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after I cloned a disk and created new virtual machine on openstack Ubuntu.

Steps to resolve:
1.cat /etc/fstab

---

/etc/fstab: static file system information.

Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device. This may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).

/ was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-do30PLgpOVFMSMdAM4yk61c90yuy3biE4jAn171mXyGByntK0sddMxpZRL1WLPmq / ext4 defaults 0 0
/boot was on /dev/vda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/1b94eedc-be13-45b6-b7c1-f9892b69296e /boot ext4 defaults 0 0
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0

2. fsck /dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-do30PLgpOVFMSMdAM4yk61c90yuy3biE4jAn171mXyGByntK0sddMxpZRL1WLPmq

---

fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 400138 has zero dtime.  Fix? yes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? yes
Inode 400139 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 400140 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 400141 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 400142 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 400333 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 420207 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -(397395--397407) -3850237 -(3852815--3852822)
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #12 (15295, counted=15308).
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #117 (5588, counted=5597).
Fix? yes
Free blocks count wrong (1462405, counted=1462427).
Fix? yes
Inode bitmap differences:  -(400138--400142) -400333 -420207
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #48 (0, counted=6).
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #51 (27, counted=28).
Fix? yes
Free inodes count wrong (935590, counted=935597).
Fix ('a' enables 'yes' to all) ? yes

/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: ***** REBOOT SYSTEM *****
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 309587/1245184 files (0.2% non-contiguous), 3517285/4979712 blocks

#reboot

After this the read only file system error has gone away.
Looks good thereafter.